# Question about rings - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the next question and got no clue.
I have shown that for $f,g \ne 0$ the coefficient of $\displaystyle x^{n+m}$ is $\displaystyle a_nb_m$ and also that $\deg(f\cdot{g}) \le n+m$.

> Let $R$ be a ring such that $\exists 1_R, \ s.t \ \forall a\in R: \quad a\cdot{1_R}=a$.
>
> Let $f,g \in R[x]$ such that $\displaystyle f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i \ , \ g=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_jx^j$ and $f,g$ are nonzero polynomials.
>
> Show that: if $\exists c \in R \ s.t \ b_m\cdot{c}=1$, then $\deg(f\cdot{g})=n+m$ where $n=\deg(f),m=\deg(g)$.

How should I tacke this question?

Answer (score 1):

You mean to use $n$ and $m$ instead of $\infty$ as the upper index of the summation symbols for $f$ and $g$, respectively. These are polynomials, not power series.

Here is a hint. Suppose $R = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 3x$. Then the conclusion fails. That's because $2$ and $3$ are zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. But there is an extra hypothesis. Can you see how it avoids the problem of zero-divisors?